# Only change img inside children li

Tags: jquery, list

Say my code is as follows:

```
<ul>
   <li><img /></li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li><img /></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to set a default size for the first `img` tag, but not affect the second one. everything I do affects the other one as well. Currently I have tried:

```
$('ul#gallery > li').find('img').css('width','650px');
$('ul#gallery > li img').css('width','650px');
```

among others, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('ul#gallery > li > img').css('width','650px');
```

Comment: Ah, I fixed it. The image was inside of an `a` tag which was throwing off jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the jQuery `:first` selector?

```
$("li img:first").css('width','650px');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: There will be about 40 images that will need to be sized, not just the first one.

Comment: You may have wanted to include that in your question.  What's the full list of requirements for the question?

Comment: Yeah that was my fault, sorry... I'll be more specific next time. It was answered above, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `id="gallery"` in your example, but assuming the following code (only the outer `<ul>` has the `gallery` id):

```
<ul id="gallery">
   <li><img /></li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li><img /></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

then the appropriate CSS selector is `ul#gallery > li > img`.

Comment: Yeah there's #gallery in my actual code, just not in the example.